# Select parent row where expand subgrid in JQGrid

Tags: asp.net, jqgrid

I have a JQGRid with two hierarchical level. I want to perform row selection when I expand a subgrid from the parent, because if I click on the plus icons, the row of the master grid is not selected. 
I am trying to fire this code whene the sub grid is expanded, but it doers not work:

```
function showSubGrid(subgrid_id, row_id)
{
    jQuery("#<%= jqGrid.ClientID %>").setSelection(row_id, true);
    showSubGrid_jqGrid(subgrid_id, row_id);
}
```

This javascript function is fired whene the subgrid is expanded from the parent. Here is my server side code:

```
<trirand:JQGrid ID="jqMasterGrid" runat="server" Height="400px" AutoWidth="False" OnSorting="jqMasterGrid_OnSorting">
<Columns>
<trirand:JQGridColumn DataField="COD_VALUTAZIONE" Width="220" HeaderText = "Codice Valutazione" PrimaryKey="True" Sortable="True" />
<trirand:JQGridColumn DataField="InfAsp" Width="170" TextAlign="Center" Sortable="True"/>
<trirand:JQGridColumn DataField="LineaAsp" Width="170" TextAlign="Center" Sortable="True"/>
<trirand:JQGridColumn DataField="SuperAsp" Width="170" TextAlign="Center" Sortable="True"/>
<trirand:JQGridColumn DataField="Eccellente" Width="170" TextAlign="Center" Sortable="True"/>
</Columns>
<ToolBarSettings
ShowAddButton="false" ShowDeleteButton="false" ShowEditButton="false" ShowRefreshButton="false"
ShowSearchButton="false" ShowViewRowDetailsButton="false" ToolBarPosition="Hidden" ShowSearchToolBar="False" ShowInlineDeleteButton="False" ShowInlineEditButton="True" />
<HierarchySettings HierarchyMode="Parent" />
<ClientSideEvents SubGridRowExpanded="showSubGrid"/>
<ClientSideEvents LoadComplete="jqLoadComplete"></ClientSideEvents>
<PagerSettings PageSize="2000" />
</trirand:JQGrid>
```

Can you please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay try something like this

```
subGridRowExpanded: function (subgrid_id, row_id) {
    $("#grid").jqGrid('setSelection', "row_id");
}
```

I can not test my code right now, but if this doesn't work then let me know.

Answer (score 3):

Use this in your parent jqgrid:

```
HierarchySettings HierarchyMode="Parent" SelectOnExpand="true"
```

By using this code when you will expand a row in parent jqgrid then the row in parent jqgrid will be selected.